# Investment loop in C

Tags: formula

I'm trying to create a compound interest loop in C that uses an array to hold multiple return rates, both positive (representing gains) and negative (representing losses).

So you start out with a principal amount and it's randomly assigned a rate from an array of rates.

I used an `if/else` inside my for loop to determine if the rate is positive or negative and what to do next. My issue is when I run it appears as if my amount variable inside the else bit (the negative rates or losses) is not being updated. Is this a pointer issue or am I totally missing something else?

```
int main()
{
    int year;
    double amount, rate, principal = 100.0;
    double rates[10] = {0.025, 0.05, 0.075, 0.1, 0.125, 0.15, -0.25, -0.2, -0.15, -0.1};

    for(year = 1; year <= 100; year++)
    {
        rate = rates[rand() % 10];

        if(rate > 0.0)
        {
            amount = principal * pow(1.0 + rate, year);
        }
        else 
        {
            rate *= -1;
            amount = principal - (principal*rate);
        }

        printf("%4d%21.2f\n", year, amount);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you require different handling for negative interest rates?  And since this is *compound* interest, why are you computing each increment based on the principal instead of the current amount?  Shouldn't it just be `amount *= (1.0 + rate);` regardless of the chosen rate?

Comment: @John Bollinger: I used this method because I can't think of a better way, hence I'm asking for help. If you have $100 and have a rate of -10% or a loss of 10% you won't get $90 as your solution if you use a straight negative rate.

Comment: Sure you will.  If the rate is -0.1, then 100 * (1 + -0.1) == 100 * .9 == 90.

Comment: Doesn't look like there is a `C` challenge here. Maybe more suitable to https://math.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @John Bollinger: please show the entire edited code, because based on your suggestions I'm not getting a functioning result.

Comment: The calculation `amount = principal * pow(1.0 + rate, year);` uses a closed-form! It calculates the new principal based on the idea that `rate` was in effect for the entire duration up to the current `year`.  That goes outside of the logic of your simulation which uses randomized rates; you cannot use a closed form formula for N years of compound interest at a fixed rate!!!

Comment: This is not a C question. Welcome to [SO]. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not make sense.

The idea appears to be a simulation of the gain / loss of a financial account over a 100-year period, with annual compound interest at a random rate each year.  It would not otherwise make sense to compute a new random rate in each iteration of the loop.  But then none of your other computations make sense.

Let's take the positive-rate case first.  For annual compound interest, each year the total balance -- principal plus accumulated interest -- earns interest at the chosen rate.  For one year, that would be

```
amount *= (1.0 + rate);
```

Instead, each year you are recomputing the amount as if interest were earned at that year's rate for all the years up to that one.  That's not only wrong, but pointless: since each iteration recomputes the amount without regard to its previous value or any other result from previous iterations, you could get the same result by performing only the last iteration of the loop.

Now consider the negative-rate case.  You are again computing based on the principal, not the current amount, so suppose we fix that first, and combine in the rate negation:

```
        amount = amount - (amount * (-rate));
```

And let's do a little algebra on that:

```
        amount = amount + (amount * rate);
```

And just a little more gets us to

```
        amount = amount * (1.0 + (1.0 * rate));
```

, which is the same as

```
        amount *= (1.0 + rate);
```

.  Now where have I seen that before?

So you were doing the computation incorrectly in both alternatives, and you never needed separate alternatives in the first place.

***Note that all this presupposes that you initialize the `amount` to equal the `principal` before the loop.***  (Otherwise, the principal would not come into it at all.)

Comment: you don't have to be an asshole about it, but thanks.

Comment: @ThomasEasterling - I'll be honest, I don't see any assholery going on here in this answer.  Just corrections to your math and your C code.  If this is how you treat people who take the time to politely and concisely help you, good luck to you in your future adventures in life.